# OpenGL Rotate, Translate, Push/Pop question

Tags: opengl

I'm pretty new to openGL, but I have been struggling with why this won't work (not trying to solve a problem necessarily, but just looking to understand the fundamentals)

So basically this draws a grid of triangles that are rotating.  What I'm trying to understand is if/how the Push and Pop operations can be removed.  When I take them out there is a random scattering.  I've  tried reversing the rotation after the drawing is complete, switching the translate and rotate commands.  I guess the way I see is that I should be able to avoid the push/pop and instead use the rotate each time to increment a few degrees further than the last time, but I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: I believe you should have your rotate in a seperate function like you glutTimerFunc (if you are using that as your framework) or some other timer function provided by GUI library you are using).

Comment: why do you want to avoid the push/pop?

Comment: I was getting very poor performance with the push pops. When I removed the push/pop and rotate, and drew at the actual location rather than translate it was 20x faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse both the translate and rotate commands (in reverse order):

```
glTranslatef(xF, yF, 0);
glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);                        

// draw

glRotatef(-angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);                        
glTranslatef(-xF, -yF, 0);
```

As @Nicol points out below, it will probably be faster to use `glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix`, since `glRotatef` requires building up a rotation matrix with sines and cosines.

What's more, a rotation followed by its inverse rotation may not be *exactly* the identity due to floating point rounding errors. This means that if you rely on this technique in an inner loop (as you do above), you may accumulate some substantial floating point errors over the course of your entire draw call.

Comment: -1 If the OP's objects are off-center then the OP will most definitely want to rotate first, then translate - otherwise he will be rotating around a non-center of mass point.

Comment: @user407462, I'm just mirroring his code - he translated first, and then rotated, so to undo that, you'd rotate, then translate. (I'm assuming his code works as he intended, which he says it does.)

Comment: That worked.  I guess the lesson I should have picked up by now is many of these operations should be performed in pairs.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ rickJames It will probably be faster if you just do the push and the pop. glRotatef requires doing sins and cosines. glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix just move a stack pointer around.

Answer (score 2):

The push/pop matrices are saving/restoring the previous matrix. You can't really avoid doing this, because you would be accumulating translations and rotations.

Remember: glTranslate does not position things. It builds a translation matrix and applies it to the *current* matrix, whatever that is. So if you do a translate, then rotate, then translate, the last translate will be in the *rotated* space, not the same space as the rotate.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL keeps an internal stack of transformation matrices. When you call [glPushMatrix()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml) it pushes all the matrices down by one, duplicating the one on the top of the list. This lets you then apply transformations, rotations, scaling etc to your hearts content, and provided you call a glPopMatrix() to remove your newly adjusted transform matrix when you're done, the rest of the 3D world won't change at all.

Note that when I say the rest of the 3D world, that includes your objects the next time your main loop loops. If you don't call glPushMatrix() and then glPopMatrix() you are permanently transforming the world and it will have an (unpredictable) effect on your objects.

So to wrap up, always call glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix() at the beginning and end of your transformations, unless you know what you're doing and want to have an effect on the rest of the 3D world.

Comment: Ya, I had run across some performance issues with using a massive number of pushes pops on some stuff I was messing around with and discovered that push/pop are not hardware accelerated leading to my issues, so I was curious how it could be done without using the two.  Thanks for the explanation though, this makes sense to my slowly growing knowledge of openGL.

Comment: @rickJames If you had massive push/pop then I'm assuming you also had massive glBegin/glEnd which is more likely to be the problem. There is a good reason push/pop are not hardware accelerated, all they do is change a pointer to point at a different matrix.

Comment: There are a lot of begin/end (over 30k), but I had also messed with using vetexPointer/colorPointer/drawArray instead and that had no noticeable difference. Removing the push/pops had a HUGE improvement.

Comment: @rickJames that's a whole lot'o begin/end. If you are drawing particles or something it would be better to put the pre-transformed positions into a vertex array and use vertexPointer to rip through them in one begin/end, rather than doing push/translate/rotate/begin/end/pop for every item. btw I am skeptical that simply removing the push/pop would have such a marked effect. In one of your comments above you mention that you 'removed the push/pop _and rotate_' - now removing a rotate, yes that would give you a speed up. Is that what you meant? ps use @iforce2d if you reply so I get notified.